# Combining a case and a Coalese in one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query with two columns I want to combine

```
Select 
  CASE WHEN ORGNBR IS NULL THEN ‘P’
       WHEN PERSNBR IS NULL THE. ‘O’
       Else null end as “owner”
  , coalesce (orgnbr,persnbr) as “owner num”
From table
```

Results

```
Owner  | Owner Num
  O    | 12345
  P    | 12899
```

Each person / org is assigned a number and I want to be able to identify an org from a person by putting an 0 in front of org numbers and a P in front of person nnbr

I want to combine these two rows so that The result will put the O in front of the ORGNBR and P I front of the PERSNBR

Expected results

```
 Owner  
  O  12345
  P 12899
```

Comment: Did the last part of your question got lost? Can you post expected outcome, I get the  impression you want to write several rows as one or?

Comment: Sorry it was cut off, I updated the post

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think I would phrase this as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ORGNBR IS NOT NULL THEN 'O' || orgnbr
             WHEN PERSNBR IS NOT NULL THEN 'P' || persnbr
        END) as owner
FROM table ;
```

(You can add additional columns if you like.)

Importantly this changes the logic so it is "positive" rather than "negative".  That is, the conditions are "if an `orgnbr` exists, then prepend a `'O'`", rather than "if an `orgnbr` does not exist, then prepend a `'P'`".  The latter is harder to follow and doesn't readily allow for more categories.

This also uses the concat operator which is more colloquial in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you want concat

```
Select 
  CASE WHEN ORGNBR IS NULL THEN 'P'
       WHEN PERSNBR IS NULL THEN 'O'
       Else null end  || coalesce (orgnbr,persnbr) as combine_row
From table
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the question, using `nvl2` is what you need :

```
with t(orgnbr,persnbr) as
(
 select  null, 12345 from dual union all
 select 12899, null  from dual 
)    
select nvl2(persnbr,'O'||persnbr,'P'||orgnbr) as "Result"
  from t;

Result
O12345
P12899
```